Android: Unable to instantiate Mainactivity class
Have searched all the forums and trouble shooting steps but I am unable to figure out the issue as to why my MainActivity class isn't being instantiated. I am new to android app development and hence struggling a lot. Have made sure package name is mentioned in manifest. still it is not working. Apologies for sharing so much code. Wanted to give full context for the problem.
2024-08-16 10:09:32.616 12426-12426 Perf                    com.example.trinity                  I  Connecting to perf service.
2024-08-16 10:09:32.627 12426-12426 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.trinity                  D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-08-16 10:09:32.628 12426-12426 NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.trinity                  D  No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2024-08-16 10:09:32.672 12426-12426 AndroidRuntime          com.example.trinity                  D  Shutting down VM
2024-08-16 10:09:32.675 12426-12426 AndroidRuntime          com.example.trinity                  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.trinity, PID: 12426
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trinity/com.example.trinity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.trinity.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.trinity/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~WP34l6wTvfxbOfRYYsDk1Q==/com.example.trinity-PS3ZXKkvRmSoCA3AWdKSzg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~WP34l6wTvfxbOfRYYsDk1Q==/com.example.trinity-PS3ZXKkvRmSoCA3AWdKSzg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3346)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3594)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7698)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.trinity.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.trinity/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes2.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~WP34l6wTvfxbOfRYYsDk1Q==/com.example.trinity-PS3ZXKkvRmSoCA3AWdKSzg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~WP34l6wTvfxbOfRYYsDk1Q==/com.example.trinity-PS3ZXKkvRmSoCA3AWdKSzg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
                                                                                                        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1254)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3334)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3594) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7698) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952) 
2024-08-16 10:09:32.698 12426-12426 Process                 com.example.trinity                  I  Sending signal. PID: 12426 SIG: 9

Here is my android manifest.xml file:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.trinity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Trinity"
        
        
        
        
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.trinity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Trinity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>

Following is mainactivity.kt file which is not getting instantiated.
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import com.example.trinity.R
import com.example.trinity.ApiHelper
import java.io.File

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var editTextQuery: EditText
    private lateinit var buttonSend: Button
    private lateinit var textViewResponse: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        editTextQuery = findViewById(R.id.editTextQuery)
        buttonSend = findViewById(R.id.buttonSend)
        textViewResponse = findViewById(R.id.textViewResponse)

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val file = File("/home/shubham/Desktop/otto_book.pdf")
                val fileId = ApiHelper.uploadFile(file)?.let { ApiHelper.createAssistant(it) }
                val responseMessage = fileId?.let { ApiHelper.sendMessage(it, editTextQuery.text.toString()) }

                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    textViewResponse.text = responseMessage
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


https://stackoverflow.com/a/78408252/13533028
This thread might help

Check that the package name in your MainActivity.kt file matches the one in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
MainActivity.kt file should begin with:
package com.example.trinity

